# ¿ Cómo usar la funcionalidad de plugins de mongoose para insertar en otra colección?

Tags: mongoose

Bueno más que todo es comparable a la funcionalidad que los procedimientos almacenados ofrecen en las bases de datos relacionales para la inserción de registros según una tabla, pero llevándolo del lado de las nosql, más específico bases de datos orientadas a documentos y más específico aun en mongodb mediante el ODM mongoose. ¿Cómo usar la funcionalidad de plugins y middleware para este propósito?

Tenemos el modelo de la colección A (A.js):

```
'use strict'
/*
 Module dependencies
*/
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

export default () => {

  let B = new Schema({
    test: String
  })

  let A = new Schema({
   test: String,
   B: [B] // embed schema
  }, { collection: 'A' })

  mongoose.model('B', B)
  return mongoose.model('A', A)
}
```

Tenemos el modelo de la colección C (C.js):

```
'use strict'
/*
  Module dependencies
*/
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import procedure from './Procedure.js'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

export default () => {

  let C = new Schema({
    test: String,
    B: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'B'
    }
  }, { collection: 'C' })

  C.plugin(procedure)
  return mongoose.model('C', C)
}
```

Ahora tenemos el plugin para manejar los históricos (Procedure.js):

```
'use strict'
/*
  Module dependencies
*/
import Historic from './Historic.js'

export default (schema, options) => {
  schema.post('save', (doc, next) => {
    //console.log(doc)
    let data = {
      test:  '313feewr',
      test2: 'dadasd41'
    }
    let h = new Historic(data)
    h.save((err) => {
      if(err) console.log(err)
      console.log(':)')
    })
    next()
  })
}
```

Ahora tenemos la colección para manejar los históricos (Historic.js):

```
'use strict'
/*
  Module dependencies
*/
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

export default () => {

  let historic = new Schema({
    test:  String,
    test2: String
  }, { collection: 'Historic' })

  return mongoose.model('Historic', historic)
}
```

Ahora mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo hago para que no me tire error y cual es la forma correcta para implementar lo que quiero?

Aclaro:

**sql**:

1. Disparadores.
2. Procedimientos almacenados.

**nosql**, mongoose:

1. Plugins.
2. Middleware.